# Left join on another join in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have a query:

```
    select a.*, b.start_date, b.end_date, c.value_text
    from 
    val_tb a
    left join 
    record_tb b on a.record_id = b.record_id
```

On the above, I need to find for each:

```
select value_text from val_tb where va_id = 26 and record_id = [record_id from above query]
```

Can I do a left join on the first query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can:

```
select a.*, b.start_date, b.end_date, c.value_text
  from val_tb a
  left join record_tb b
    on a.record_id = b.record_id
  left join val_tb c
    on a.record_id = c.record_id
   and c.va_id = 26
```